# Huge performance difference between Write-Back and Write-Through memory for read-only operation

Tags: performance, memory, x86-64, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

As per Intel's software manual, read on write-through memory is mentioned as ***Reads come from cache lines on cache hits; read misses cause cache fills***. So according to this, if we do only read operation, then the performance of WT should be equal to WriteBack (WB). Apparently it is not the case.

I have performed sequential read-only on an 1 GB mmap area (created with MAP_POPULATE to avoid page faults) on an x86-64 system and the time taken (measured using RDTSC) to perform 2^20 sequential integer reads for WB and WT has a huge difference as shown below. These values are average of multiple runs.

```
WB: 7506306
WT: 344950734
```

I am not able to understand, why such a huge difference in WB and WT performance on read?

Any pointers to explore further on this to see the real cause.

```
code used,
Ignore MAP_PERSISTENT|MAP_SENSITIVE flags,
which are added to enable pwt in page_table setup through kernel module
--------------------------------------
#define SIZE 1<<30

int main(){
    uint32_t start_hi, start_lo, end_hi, end_lo;
    int* ptr;
    int a;
    int loop_index;
    ptr = (int*)mmap(NULL,SIZE,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PERSISTENT|MAP_SENSITIVE|MAP_POPULATE,-1,0);
    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED){
        perror("mmap");
        exit(-1);
    }

    RDTSC_START();
    for(loop_index=0;loop_index<1048576;loop_index++){
        a = ptr[loop_index];
    }
    RDTSC_STOP();
    printf("elapsed time:%lu\n",elapsed(start_hi,start_lo,end_hi,end_lo));
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Could you include your test code?

Comment: Your WB number gives an average of 7.15 reference cycles per integer read.  I guess you mean each read was a separate cache line?  Because that's an average bandwidth of ~9 bytes per reference-cycle for 64-byte line fills, which is somewhat reasonable for sequential-read bandwidth depending on the reference clock frequency on whatever CPU model you have, vs. DRAM memory bandwidth (e.g. DDR3-1600 vs. DDR4-2666 or whatever.)

Comment: The WT performance being ~50x slower seems unreasonable unless HW prefetch was disabled for some reason.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I have included the code that I have used, Thanks for your comment

Comment: @PeterCordes : I have not disabled HW prefetchers. I have also included the code which I used to give clarity on the reads I am doing. I defined WT by setting 3rd bit (pwt bit) in page structure entry (pte) that points to 4KB page.

Comment: And you compile this with optimization disabled?  Otherwise the memory access should optimize away.  And I guess `-O0` keeping the loop counter in memory (store-forwarding bottleneck) explains why you're only going at 1 load per 7 clocks, despite touching every `int`.  If you'd used `volatile int*` and compiled with optimization, you'd expect 2 loads per clock.  There are 16 `int`s in a cache line, so that's still only 1 cache line per 8 clocks best case because you're using such narrow loads.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I compiled with -O0. Thanks for your comment